# Is this question worth migrating?

Tags: discussion, specific-question, vote-to-close, migration

I'm asking about [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/44643510/recover-from-corrupted-redo-files-in-oracle-12c-when-db-engine-fails-to-start). The question is about Oracle administration, not programming, so my first thought was to vote to migrate to DBA Stack Exchange.

Ordinarily, the rule is "migrate if it would be a reasonable question on another site, vote to close and/or downvote otherwise." So, my question is: *is* this an unreasonable question? Should this be migrated or closed outright?

In case the question ends up being deleted, here's an abbreviated version (stripped of the logs for brevity):

> I have an Oracle 12.0.1.2.0 (Enterprise package) installation on my Windows 7 development machine. After an unexpected power failure, the Oracle engine fails to start:
>
> [Error message]
>
> Consequently, I am unable to connect with SQLplus to execute any commands and hence, none of the guides I found online to clear the REDO files works for me.
> [Log...]
>
> This is the startup log...
>
> [Log..]
>
> And here is the trace dump file (orcl_ora_4864.trc):
>
> [Log...]
>
> Now my question is: Is there a way for me to fix this issue without reinstalling Oracle? I am not concerned with data loss since it is not production data, I just hope to avoid setting up my local databases again since I am on the clock...
> Any help is highly appreciated...

Comment: You know, at first blush this doesn't look half bad. But I'm not a DBA mod...

Comment: @BoltClock As of right now, it has a positive score of one (2 upvotes, one downvote). Full disclosure: I was one of the upvoters (because I'd like to see the answer to it, too).

Comment: I sent it over.

Comment: It has been migrated

Answer (score 15, accepted):

I sure hope it can be migrated.  Apparently a 3-2 majority on the migration isn't enough to convince the system to migrate.

This is the sort of question that [is actually on-topic](https://dba.stackexchange.com/help/on-topic) there.

> Database Administration including configuration and backup / restore

Since this question is pertaining to configuring their database, I don't see a reason why it couldn't live over there.  It's something that Stack Overflow users *might* know something about, but I feel like they'd get more pointed help if their question was over there instead.

Comment: Yeah, you need 4 votes to migrate. Err on the side of caution and everything...

Comment: Fair enough.  Should really look into these things closer, but migrating questions don't normally happen these days.

Comment: SO is the only site on the network where supermayority isn't enough for migration.

Comment: 4 votes at SO are there since 2011 @BoltClock - see [Require more than simple majority of close votes to migrate](https://meta.stackexchange.com/a/97700/165773)

Comment: @gnat: Why are you telling me this? Or did you mean to say "in addition to what BoltClock said"?

Comment: @BoltClock yes in addition to what you said